# C# / .Net Youtube V3 API, Issue listing items to control

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, youtube-data-api

I currently am working on a small test project with the YouTube API.
What I am trying to achieve is pretty simple : I do a search request with the API get the title and video ID and I put those in a DataTable.
From there I want to make a button out of each result and add these to a FlowLayoutPanel so what I figured was use a foreach loop. But the issue that's presenting itself here is when I got over 100+ results it seems to throw errors (I guess windows forms doesn't like making 100+ buttons)

What I want to know is can I make my code more efficient and can I for example add 2 buttons below to show the "next" and "previous" 100 results. So it will only load 100 at a time.

Below is my code it may be a bit messy since I am pretty new to c#.

This is the button I use to start the search.

```
    private void Youtube_Search_Video_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Search_Vid = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;
        if (Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text == "Search video" || Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text == "")
        {
            Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text = "Search video";
        }
        if (Search_Vid != null && Search_Vid != "Search video" && Search_Vid != Last_Search_Vid)
        {
            Last_Search_Vid = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;

            search_results_vids.Clear();
            if (search_results_vids.Columns.Count.Equals(0)) {
                search_results_vids.Columns.Add("VideoTitle");
                search_results_vids.Columns.Add("VideoID");
            }

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status : Searching...";
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
```

Which starts the backgroundworker below. (Oh and of course the datatable creating before that.)

```
    public DataTable search_results_vids = new DataTable();


    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString(),
            ApiKey = "MyApiKeY",
        });
        var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
            var listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
            listRequest.Q = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;
            listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            listRequest.Type = "video";
            listRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

            var resp = listRequest.Execute();
            List<string> videos = new List<string>();

            foreach (SearchResult result in resp.Items)
            {
                switch (result.Id.Kind)
                {
                    case "youtube#video":
                        object[] newsearchresult = { result.Snippet.Title, result.Id.VideoId};
                        search_results_vids.Rows.Add(newsearchresult);

                        break;
                }

            }

            nextPageToken = resp.NextPageToken;

        }


    }
```

And when it finishes.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in search_results_vids.Rows)
        {

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = row["VideoTitle"].ToString();
            if (button.Text.Length >= 35)
            {
                button.Text.Remove(button.Text.Length - (button.Text.Length - 35));
            }
            button.Tag = row["VideoID"];
            button.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            button.ForeColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
            button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
            button.Width = (flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 120);
            button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
            button.Height = 35;
            button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 10);
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);

        }
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status : Listing Videos, Please Wait...";
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Results : " + search_results_vids.Rows.Count.ToString();

    }
```

I've tried adding the Foreach loop into the DoWork part of the backgroundworker but then it seems to skip it all together. Any help is very welcome and if I did anything wrong please let me know (Still learning!)

Edit : To clarify it's the button creation part I am stuck at. Listing the items from the table to a listview works fine. All the button settings seem to have to do with the loading time of them. So that's why I want to try an approach where I load only 100 per "page" from the DataTable. I only have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can Add Buttons in the Same Loop(**backgroundWorker1_DoWork**) ,Just Make Sure that Adding/Changing UI should be in different Thread ...Otherwise You Would get Cross-Thread Exception.
so One Way to do is

```
 Action actUI = ()=>{

                      Button button = new Button();
                      button.Text = get Data from newsearchresult ;
                      if (button.Text.Length >= 35)
                      {
                         button.Text.Remove(button.Text.Length - (button.Text.Length - 35));
                      }
                     button.Tag = get Data from newsearchresult ;;
                     button.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                     button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                     button.ForeColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                     button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                     button.Width = (flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 120);
                     button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                     button.Height = 35;
                     button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 10);
                     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
                  };

            if(flowLayoutPanel1.InvokeRequired)
              flowLayoutPanel1.BeginInvoke(actUI);
            else
              flowLayoutPanel1.Invoke(actUI);
```

Comment: Hey this seems very helpful! But I've only recently started with c# so could you maybe point me in the right direction where I can read more about this? I've read a bit about the InvokeRequired and figured I needed that for the UI part to work in the backgroundworker. But I do not quite yet understand the use of it.  Also does button.Tag = get Data from newsearchresult ; get the right item and how does it know to take the second item? (Sorry for the noob questions haha)

Comment: And sorry for another question : I assume the flowlayoutpanel invokerequired  part goes in the loop? But where do I add the action?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be looking into bringing your results in pages.

[YouTube API - Pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination)

Comment: Hmm but the youtube search isn't the issue that takes only like 2 seconds in the backgroundworker. I could list it to text only in a listview and it's all working fine. The issue is that the forms application simply gives up when I ask it to create all those buttons instead of the listview format. So I guess what I am asking is how would one approach pagination over the datatable? Ps. I am using pagination for the search result already listRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;