# C# How can I run this code in a background thread?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visual-studio-2015

So I've been stuck on this for a while. (Forms application)

I want this to run in the "Background".
I normally call it with the "search button".

So far I've read you can't access UI stuff in another thread? So how would I approach this and make the UI accessible while it loads the results and converts them into buttons?
Is there any easy way to do this for someone who just started out with C#?

Code below :

```
    private void Search_Video_Youtube(string page)
    {
        YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString(),
            ApiKey = "*MyApiKeyGoesHere*",
        });

        var listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
        listRequest.Q = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;
        listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        listRequest.Type = "video";
        listRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
        video_results_vids = video_results_vids + 50;

        var resp = listRequest.Execute();
        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        foreach (SearchResult result in resp.Items)
        {
            switch (result.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();
                    picturebox.Height = 100;
                    picturebox.Width = 100;
                    picturebox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                    picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;        
                    string template2 = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/{0}{1}";
                    string data2 = result.Id.VideoId.ToString();
                    string quality2 = "/default.jpg";
                    string messageB = string.Format(template2, data2, quality2);

                    var request = WebRequest.Create(messageB);
                    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        picturebox.Image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                    }
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picturebox);


                    listnumber += 1;
                    Button button = new Button();

                    button.Text = listnumber.ToString() + " " + result.Snippet.Title.ToString();
                    button.Tag = result.Id.VideoId;
                    button.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                    button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    button.ForeColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                    button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                    button.Width = (flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 150);
                    button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;                        
                    button.Height = 100;
                    button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 10);
                    button.Click += (s, e) => {
                        Youtube_video_Player_hider.Visible = false;
                        var a = result.Id.VideoId;
                        string template = "https://www.youtube.com/v/{0}{1}";
                        string data = a.ToString();
                        string quality = Video_Quality;
                        string messagea = string.Format(template, data, quality);
                        axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = messagea;
                        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
                    };
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);

                    break;
            }
        }
        nextPageToken = resp.NextPageToken;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status : Idle";
        toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Results : " + video_results_vids;
    }
```

Any help is welcome but please explain it in detail as I am very new to C# but I do have a basic programming knowledge.
(Also if you see anything I could do better feel free to point it out, am here to learn :) )

EDIT : Thanks to Jeroen van langen (Answer below) I figured it out. 
The current code is now :

```
// At using Stuff
using ExtensionMethods;

    private void Search_Video_Youtube(string page)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((state) =>
        {
            YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString(),
                ApiKey = "ThisIsTheApiKeyYouTubeWantsForAnyoneWondering",
            });

            var listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
            listRequest.Q = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;
            listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            listRequest.Type = "video";
            listRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
            video_results_vids = video_results_vids + 50;

            var resp = listRequest.Execute();
            List<string> videos = new List<string>();
            Parallel.ForEach(resp.Items, (SearchResult result) =>
            {

                switch (result.Id.Kind)
                {
                    case "youtube#video":
                        string template2 = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/{0}{1}";
                        string data2 = result.Id.VideoId.ToString();
                        string quality2 = "/default.jpg";
                        string messageB = string.Format(template2, data2, quality2);
                        Image image;
                        var request = WebRequest.Create(messageB);
                        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                        }


                        listnumber += 1;

                        this.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();
                            picturebox.Height = 100;
                            picturebox.Width = 100;
                            picturebox.Image = image;
                            picturebox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                            picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

                            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picturebox);

                            Button button = new Button();

                            button.Text = listnumber.ToString() + " " + result.Snippet.Title.ToString();
                            button.Tag = result.Id.VideoId;
                            button.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                            button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                            button.ForeColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                            button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                            button.Width = (flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 150);
                            button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
                            button.Height = 100;
                            button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 10);
                            button.Click += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                Youtube_video_Player_hider.Visible = false;
                                var a = result.Id.VideoId;
                                string template = "https://www.youtube.com/v/{0}{1}";
                                string data = a.ToString();
                                string quality = Video_Quality;
                                string messagea = string.Format(template, data, quality);
                                axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = messagea;
                                axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
                            };
                            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
                        });
                        break;
                }

                nextPageToken = resp.NextPageToken;

                this.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status : Idle";
                    toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Results : " + video_results_vids;
                });
            });

        }));
    }
```

Class Contents :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void Invoke(this Control control, Action action)
        {
            control.Invoke((Delegate)action);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well the most time consuming part seem's to be the loading of 50 buttons.
I had my code like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763971/c-sharp-net-youtube-v3-api-issue-listing-items-to-control/35764318#35764318 before this which gave it's own problems =\ .  And with GUI thread I assume that's where everything normally gets executed right? It's been a bit confusing with C# so far so sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: You can't directly access objects created by the UI thread from a different thread. However, you **can** jump threads, or make a `BeginInvoke` call to the UI thread, in order to update/modify its controls. Lots of examples on the internet...  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should execute the 'whole' method on a thread. Try to move all creation of controls to one section and invoke that part on the GUI thread. The most consuming time will be the WebRequests

PSEUDO:   something like:

```
private void Search_Video_Youtube(string page)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((state) =>
    {
        YouTubeService youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString(),
            ApiKey = "*MyApiKeyGoesHere*",
        });

        var listRequest = youtube.Search.List("snippet");
        listRequest.Q = Youtube_SearchVideo_Box.Text;
        listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
        listRequest.Type = "video";
        listRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
        video_results_vids = video_results_vids + 50;

        var resp = listRequest.Execute().OfType<SearchResult>();
        List<string> videos = new List<string>();
        Parallel.Foreach(resp.Items, (result) =>
        {

            switch (result.Id.Kind)
            {
                case "youtube#video":
                    string template2 = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/{0}{1}";
                    string data2 = result.Id.VideoId.ToString();
                    string quality2 = "/default.jpg";
                    string messageB = string.Format(template2, data2, quality2);
                    Bitmap image;
                    var request = WebRequest.Create(messageB);
                    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        image = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);
                    }


                    listnumber += 1;

                    this.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();
                        picturebox.Height = 100;
                        picturebox.Width = 100;
                        picturebox.Image = image;
                        picturebox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                        picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;        

                        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(picturebox);

                        Button button = new Button();

                        button.Text = listnumber.ToString() + " " + result.Snippet.Title.ToString();
                        button.Tag = result.Id.VideoId;
                        button.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
                        button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                        button.ForeColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
                        button.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue;
                        button.Width = (flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 150);
                        button.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;                        
                        button.Height = 100;
                        button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, 10);
                        button.Click += (s, e) => {
                            Youtube_video_Player_hider.Visible = false;
                            var a = result.Id.VideoId;
                            string template = "https://www.youtube.com/v/{0}{1}";
                            string data = a.ToString();
                            string quality = Video_Quality;
                            string messagea = string.Format(template, data, quality);    
                            axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = messagea;
                            axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
                        };
                        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button);
                    });
                    break;
            }

        nextPageToken = resp.NextPageToken;

        this.Invoke(() =>
        {
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status : Idle";
            toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = "Results : " + video_results_vids;
        });
    }, null);

}
```

Comment: Going to play around with this ! Looks very helpful and less complicated then what i've seen so far! Will get back to this in a few minutes!

Comment: I wrote this within the browser, so don't judge the Syntax checking. It's just an example. You'll probably know how to invoke etc..

Comment: Honestly not 100% yet, Like I stated pretty new to C# and the documentation is all over the place when you google. (A lot of results for older versions and I often stumble upon newer methods of using stuff (Like what you are doing here , I've seen very complicated versions of it which just made my brain give up)  So if you got a link where I can read some proper documentation about it would be nice. 

I've stumbled upon one problem so far : I can't access result.Id.Kind at the Switch ( result.Id.Kind) Says it does not exist.

Comment: The problem with the `result.Id.Kind` is probably because the `listRequest.Execute();` doesn't return a `IEnumerable<SearchResult>`, but something as an `IEnumberable<object>`. And in your situation it works because the foreach loop does the cast. ... You can fix this with: `var resp = listRequest.Execute().OfType<SearchResult>();`  (changed in code..)

Comment: Hey that wasn't an issue it were a few other things (Error list displayed what and where :D ) Last thing that now shows it in all red underline is :  Delegate 'WaitCallback' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: I updated my example, and google is your friend: Here is some more information about the `ThreadPool`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks going to approve your answer as I almost got it to work now and that's a lot better then where I was at. Going to read the links you gave and figure this out (Last error is the .OfType<SearchResult>(); thing it says it has no definition) but I guess more will come thanks for the help anyhow!  When I get this to work I will know how to use it in the future.

Comment: Hey Jeroen I just got it to work! Also made me learn how to add my own ExtensionMethods class. It sped up the search results by a ton. The few Syntax errors made me even understand it a bit more since it made me pick apart the code again and see what was going on. Thanks again!

Comment: The speed improvement is because the results are done parallel _(all requests are queued on the ThreadPool)_. Only creating controls are executed on the mainthread... Like I said, executing the WebRequest will be the bottleneck.  and...   you're welcome..   ;-)

Comment: Ahh that explains a lot! Going to try this out with a few other things and see how it preforms :). By the way we happen to come from the same country! _In dutch_ : Dus nogmaals bedankt! _In English_ So again thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate that takes argument of type of `resp`

```
public delegate void ListDispatcher(var resp)
```

remember, var needs to be replaced with the exact type of the `resp`.

Now create a ListDispatcher reference member in the main class.

```
public ListDispatcher dispatcher;
```

and add a new method to its invocation list.

```
dispatcher += MyNewMethod;
```

Define the new method as

```
public void MyNewMethod(var resp){

//Move all your controls creation code here

}
```

Remove the code after the call

```
var resp = listRequest.Execute();
```

and simply put there

```
dispatcher(resp);
```

Now you can safely call the `Search_Video_Youtube(string page)` in a separate thread.